# cWhat is the importance of Multiplicative Group in Number Theory

Tags: group-theory, cryptography

I'm studying Number theory basics for Cryptography Course. There is a term called Multiplicative Group which confuses me litle bit

I know $|\mathbb Z_n^*| = \phi(n)$ (Euler Phi Function) and

$\mathbb Z_n^* = \{ a \in \mathbb Z_n | gcd(a,n) = 1 \}$

I think it has to do something with inverses, But I'm not sure. Can anybody explain this group structure. How is it helpful and where ..

Comment: If I Google for "multiplicative group" the very first result answers your question. Have you tried?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I tried wiki and other websites, But didn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the requirements for a group is that every element has an inverse. For $\mathbb{Z}_n$ groups under multiplication, the only elements that have multiplicative inverses are those which are relatively prime to $n$. Or in symbols, $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ if and only if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. Euler's phi function comes into play because it counts all such $a$.